# How to call EditTable method of UITableView from some other class?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, row, edit

I want to edit UITableView by calling EditTable method on a button click of some other class. In other words, I want to delete rows from UITableview from some other viewcontroller without navigating to that UITableView.

Please tell me the way to achieve this or any sample code for it.

Comment: Did you have your table view controller on your stack of views?

Comment: No, thats simple view controller which contains table view as IBOutlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete rows from a tableview you just need to delete the corresponding rows from the datasource. When the table is next shown it should know how to reload it's data so the changes in the datasource are applied to the table.

**Edit**

You shouldn't rely on sending messages to view controllers that are deeper in the stack because they may have been unloaded already.